# swift handle variable arguments of different template types

Tags: swift, generics

My actual problem is much more complicated than this - I'm not just writing a strange way of creating tuples, I've just simplified it here to explain the problem...

I'm wondering if there's any way to not have to write out every separate case - because especially in the real thing where I've gotta do *work* for every field - there's a massive amount of duplicate code.   So... suppose you wanted to make a function that creates tuples - at the moment I'm doing the equivalent of:

```swift
func create<Ta,Tb>( v1 : Ta, v2 : Tb ) -> (Ta, Tb )
{ return (v1, v2);}

func create<Ta,Tb,Tc>( v1: Ta, v2: Tb, v3: Tc) -> (Ta,Tb,Tc)
{ return (v1, v2, v3 );}

func create<Ta,Tb,Tc,Td>( v1 : Ta, v2: Tb, v3: Tc, v4 : Td) -> (Ta, Tb, Tc, Td) 
{ return (v1,v2,v3,v4 );}

...
```

Just wondering if anyone can think of a better way.  It's very important that the resulting tuples are *typed* - ie not some polymorphic collection - because they don't get used like a collection - it wouldn't make sense to iterate over the result - they are all explicitly and separately used by code.

Comment: Instead of using generics, why don't you use `Any` as the type? Then, you need to test for the type when you read the values: `switch case let doubleValue as Double:..., case let intValue as Int:... case let stringValue as String:...`

Comment: I'm writing a library that will be used lots - I'll do any amount of work in the library to make the usage of it simpler / harder to break.   And hey - what I'm doing works perfectly - it's just a lot of repeated code.

Comment: There is no reasonable way. Look at the [merge](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/just/merge(with:)) operator in the Combine Framework. If there was a way Apple would have certainly used it.

Comment: For builders, it needs indeed to be written manually. Apple builders have also limitation on number of arguments. But, you could also use Stencil to generate that code. It might be a little extra, depending on what's really inside the function, but that should work to automatize the writing of them.